# spooling a clob value with multiple lines using sqlplus to a single cell of a CSV

Tags: oracle, csv, spreadsheet, sqlplus, clob

I tried to spool a CLOB to a CSV file using code that looks like below:

```
set pagesize 0
set heading off
set long 30000
set longchunksize 30000


SPOOL test.csv


select text from user_views;
```

But the above code returns the CLOB as multiple rows because of newline/carriage returns in the CLOB in the resulting CSV when viewed from a spreadsheet program(OOcalc). Is there anyway to keep the whole CLOB intact in a single cell?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look at the DBMS_LOB package for ideas on how to get the data out of there cleanly.